# How to assign value that i get from user in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have some variable dynamically change color in this:

```
ctxt.strokeStyle = "black";
```

How to assign or call function that I get as input:

```js
function ChangeBackgroundFont(selectTag, type) {
  if (type == "font") {
    // Returns the index of the selected option
    var whichSelected = selectTag.selectedIndex;
    // Returns the selected options values
    var selectState = selectTag.options[whichSelected].text;
    var fontTest = document.getElementById("fontbackgroundTest");
    if ('fontSizeAdjust' in fontTest.style) {
      fontTest.style.fontSizeAdjust = selectState;
    } else {
      alert("Your browser doesn't support this example!");
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("fontbackgroundTest").style.color = selectTag.value;
  }

}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form>

    <select name="color" type="text" onchange="ChangeBackgroundFont(this,'background');">
      <option value="select">Select</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      <option value="green">Green</option>
      <option value="white">White</option>
      <option value="black">Black</option>
    </select>
    <span id="fontbackgroundTest">Change font-size-adjust</span>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

should I call JS function or assign ID. can you help me ?

Example I want change the result text color based on user input:

```
<head>

        <meta name="keywords" content="JavaScript, UserInput" />
        <title>JavaScript accept user input demo</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function displayOutput() {
                var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
                if (input.length === 0) {
                    alert("Please enter a valid input");
                    return;
                }
               document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have entered " + input;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="result">JavaScript Example</h1>
        <input type="text" id="userInput"  />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="displayOutput()" />
    </body>
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem from your question. The code appears to work from the snippet.

Comment: I have seperate Javascript file. In that, One variable for assign font strokestyle color. I have to get color from user input and assign that value to that variable.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear, could you elaborate on what you'd like to have as a result? All I can understand from your question is that you want the text to change when the select field changes value, and that works. EDIT: Then place that javascript file in your question

Comment: Yeah Its working but I have to assign that color value to another javascript function variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this where you want to get the color:

```
  // You may want to give your <select> a class or an id to have a more reliable way of retrieving it from JavaScript
  var select = document.querySelector('select[name="color"]');
  var selectState = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;

  ctxt.strokeStyle = selectState.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Could you try my example code with this to change the color of result ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most compute efficient, if I understand what your asking.

[Here is a live instance **DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/qkmLhvdg/)

//HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
      <select id='dropdown'>
           <option selected disabled>Select</option>
           <option value="blue">Blue</option>
           <option value="green">Green</option>
           <option value="white">White</option>
           <option value="black">Black</option>
       </select>
    </form>
    <span id="colorMe">Change font-size-adjust</span>
</body>
</html>
```

//JS

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);

function init(){
    document.getElementById('dropdown').addEventListener('change', change.dropdown);
}
var change = {
    "dropdown": function(e){
        document.getElementById('colorMe').style.color = e.target.value;
    }
};
```